# Populating calendar looping through 10 mysql tables

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

I have a question of how to proceed with the following:

I want to create an input box to enter a start date in php, mysql and maybe javascript.
Then I have 10 tables in a database I want to "populate" the next 90 days with the table data from the date set.

So it would be, day 1 to 10 = table 1 to 10 and then day 20 to 30 = tables 1 to 10 etc. So it loops over and over.

This would all be specific to each user in the database, so users could each have a separate start date.

So ultimately, when a user logs in i would use something like a jQuery datepicker, and when a user clicks on a date
after the start date, and before the end date, that specific table would show for that specific day.

It would also be nice to create a little more advanced version, where the user can choose to skip the current day, then the rest of the days would shift one day forward. (if at all possible)

It is kind of hard to explain, but I would appreciate it very much if at least someone could point me in the right direction :)

Sincerely
OmiCron

Answer (score 1):

Your database setup is wrong.

- make a **single** table
- store only actual events, do not pre-populate it with empty events
- select all events for the given period using SQL query

that's all

if you need to assign users to events, another cross-table is required. consists of only 2 columns - user id and event id. it will let you to assign whatever number of users to whatever events and select them easily

Comment: thats the idea of sql :)